# Delay an Event Listener until login (Firebase: Simple Login.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, callback, dom-events

I'm writing a simple page to better understand the Firebase Simple Login system. You can find a link to it at http://jsfiddle.net/ShrsN/.

I understand the Simple Login basics, and I think I understand Firebase's data-reading callbacks (`.on('child_added')`, and such). However, I suspect my code needs some reworking, because this following listener is reliant on userRef being assigned its proper value. While userRef is properly defined earlier in the code--once a user clicks OK to login--, I believe that the asynchronicity of the code means that the `userRef.on('child_added'){}` block is trying to be run before `userRef` is defined properly.

```
userRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.val() === null) {
        alert('User does not exist.');
    } else {
        console.log("Child added" + snapshot);
    }
});
```

My console gives me this warning: `FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for /users/undefined failed: Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.` and I'm pretty sure it's because userRef.on is being tried on pageload, while userRef is only defined once the user logs in. (Again, see the jsfiddle for exactly how that works).

So, how can I 'pause' or postpone this `userRef.on()` block until the user has logged in? I'm not 100% clear on how this method works: Can I put it in a conditional? Will it still trigger properly if inside another function?

Comment: Perhaps typing out my problem gave me insight into solving it. For posterity, here's a link to the jsfiddle where I refactored the listener into the login function, right after userRef was set. http://jsfiddle.net/37shg/

Comment: You used the dev teddy! One of my favorite was to solve a problem; explain it to someone else and watch the answer magically appear!